# mongoDB - add custom field by another document field, with pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have `user schema` and `invitation schema`.
When user search for users I want to return array with object that have property `invited`.

```
const InvitationSchema = new Schema<IInvitation>(
    {
        sender: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user'
        },
        receiver: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user'
        }
    }
)
const IUserSchema = new Schema<IUser>(
    {
        email: {
            type: String,
        },
        invitedUsers: [
            {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user'
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Scenario of my problem:

1. There are 3 users with ids - userId1, userId2, userId3
2. User1 sends invitation to User2.
   So current db becomes:

```
user1:{
  id:userId1,
  invitedUsers:[userId2]
}

invitation1:{
  id:someId,
  sender:userId1,
  receiver:userId2
}
```

3. Here User1 make a user search request to the server and receive:

```
users:[
  {
     id:userId2,
     invited:true
  },
  {
     id:userId3,
     invited:false
  },
]
```

I also want to paginated users but its not target of the current problem.

I tried some variants with aggregation $addFields but nothing works. The other way to do 10 queries more as the users per page are 10. This is bad idea of course.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the expected response for this data, so we could help

Comment: @nimrodserok I added what adviced me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice question. One option is to do it with `$lookup`:

1. The first 4 steps here are regarding your pagination, returning only the number of documents you need, after sorting, skipping, limiting and remove the user who request the search.
2. Then we use the $lookup` to add the details of the requestingUserId, including the list of invited user ids on each one of our selected documents.
3. Now all is left is to check for each document if its own `id` is included at the `invitedUsers` we got from the requesting user.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match: {id: {$ne: requestingUserId}}},
  {$sort: {id: 1}},
  {$skip: 1},
  {$limit: 2},
  {$addFields: {invitedBy: requestingUserId }},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "invitedBy",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "invited"
    }
  },
  {$set: {invited: {$first: "$invited"}}},
  {
    $project: {
      invited: {$cond: [{$in: ["$id", "$invited.invitedUsers"]}, true, false] },
      id: 1, _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M2mvz8NOjEq)

You can also improve the performance by using the `$lookup` pipeline to bring only the part you need:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match: {id: {$ne: requestingUserId}}},
  {$sort: {id: 1}},
  {$skip: 1},
  {$limit: 2},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {myId: "$id"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {id: "userId1"}},
        {$project: {res: {$cond: [{$in: ["$$myId", "$invitedUsers"]}, true, false]}}}
      ],
      as: "invited"
    }
  },
  {$project: {invited: {$first: "$invited.res"}, id: 1, _id: 0}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - lookup-pipeline](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jAxrCHXcjUQ)

Comment: In first example I cannot understand the purpose of this: `{$set: {invited: {$first: "$invited"}}}`

Comment: For example: I removed `{$set: {invited: {$first: "$invited"}}}` and change `$in: ["$id","$invited.0.invitedUsers" ]` but this not working. https://mongoplayground.net/p/-MvB1VF2BD7

Comment: I'm not familiar with `"$invited.0.invitedUsers"` inside an aggregation pipeline. I tried it on the playground and it does not seems to work. If it would work, it would indeed allow to drop `{$set: {invited: {$first: "$invited"}}}` from the first option.

Comment: Im using mongoose with typescript and just added the answer to my code. What I changed to work is where I use `_id -> requestingUserId` I changed to `_id -> new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(requestingUserId)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the `invitedUsers` array has some length, then return true, otherwise false, then this could be done with aggregate

```
User.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      invitedUsers: {
        $cond: [
          { $gt: [{ $size:"$invitedUsers" }, 0] },
          true,
          false,
        ],
      }
    }
  }
])
```

explore aggregate [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html)